# In Pandas, How to use fillna to fill the whole columns with string if the column is empty originally?

Tags: python, pandas

My table:

```
In [15]: csv=u"""a,a,,a
   ....: b,b,,b
   ....: c,c,,c
   ....: """

In [18]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), header=None)
```

Fill the empty columns as 'UNKNOWN'

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
   0  1   2  3
0  a  a NaN  a
1  b  b NaN  b
2  c  c NaN  c

In [20]: df.fillna({2:'UNKNOWN'})
```

Got the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: UNKNOWN
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `2` column probably has a float dtype:

```
>>> df
   0  1   2  3
0  a  a NaN  a
1  b  b NaN  b
2  c  c NaN  c
>>> df.dtypes
0     object
1     object
2    float64
3     object
dtype: object
```

Hence the problem.  If you don't mind converting the whole frame to `object`, you could:

```
>>> df.astype(object).fillna("UNKNOWN")
   0  1        2  3
0  a  a  UNKNOWN  a
1  b  b  UNKNOWN  b
2  c  c  UNKNOWN  c
```

Depending on whether there's non-string data you might want to be more selective about converting column dtypes, and/or specify the dtypes on read, but the above should work, anyhow.

---

Update: if you have dtype information you want to preserve, rather than switching it back, I'd go the other way and only fill on the columns that you wanted to, either using a loop with `fillna`:

```
>>> df
   0  1  2   3  4   5
0  0  a  a NaN  a NaN
1  1  b  b NaN  b NaN
2  2  c  c NaN  c NaN
>>> df.dtypes
0      int64
1     object
2     object
3    float64
4     object
5    float64
dtype: object
>>> for col in df.columns[pd.isnull(df).all()]:
...         df[col] = df[col].astype(object).fillna("UNKNOWN")
...     
>>> df
   0  1  2        3  4        5
0  0  a  a  UNKNOWN  a  UNKNOWN
1  1  b  b  UNKNOWN  b  UNKNOWN
2  2  c  c  UNKNOWN  c  UNKNOWN
>>> df.dtypes
0     int64
1    object
2    object
3    object
4    object
5    object
dtype: object
```

Or (if you're using `all`), then maybe not even use `fillna` at all:

```
>>> df
   0  1  2   3  4   5
0  0  a  a NaN  a NaN
1  1  b  b NaN  b NaN
2  2  c  c NaN  c NaN
>>> df.ix[:,pd.isnull(df).all()] = "UNKNOWN"
>>> df
   0  1  2        3  4        5
0  0  a  a  UNKNOWN  a  UNKNOWN
1  1  b  b  UNKNOWN  b  UNKNOWN
2  2  c  c  UNKNOWN  c  UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have some int type columns, so should I convert them back?

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, just set the column directly, the fillna upconversion should work and is a bug

```
In [8]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), header=None)

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
   0  1   2  3
0  a  a NaN  a
1  b  b NaN  b
2  c  c NaN  c

In [10]: df.loc[:,2] = 'foo'

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
   0  1    2  3
0  a  a  foo  a
1  b  b  foo  b
2  c  c  foo  c

In [12]: df.dtypes
Out[12]: 
0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution;)

Comment: this is actually a very tricky bug to fix, as numpy has an issue with converting a float dtype to object in-place, see this issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3217

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:['a','b','c'], 1:['a','b','c'], 2:np.nan, 3:['a','b','c']})
df

    0   1   2   3
0   a   a   NaN a
1   b   b   NaN b
2   c   c   NaN c
```

you could do this by specifying the name of the column inside square brackets and using `fillna`:

```
df[2].fillna('UNKNOWN', inplace=True)
```

If you print `df`, it will be like this:

```
    0   1         2  3
0   a   a   UNKNOWN  a
1   b   b   UNKNOWN  b
2   c   c   UNKNOWN  c
```

you could fill all empty cells in all the columns by:

```
df.fillna('UNKNOWN', inplace=True)
```